# why gt summary gives me 2 different p-values

Tags: r, p-value, gtsummary

I try to get some tables with tbl_summary but if I don't specify which test I want to use in add_p() it gives me a p value and if I specify that I want to use the "chisq.test" it gives me another value, which is strange because according to the vignette the default test is chisq.test.

Does anyone know which test can be used or why I get this difference?

Thank you very much.

**Here is my reproducible example:**

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2), b = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", 
"red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", 
"red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", 
"blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", 
"blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", 
"blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"red", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "red", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -207L))
```

```
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
      a b    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 blue 
2     2 blue 
3     1 blue 
4     1 blue 
5     2 blue 
6     1 blue
```

**This is what I get with default test**

```
df %>%
  select(a, b) %>%
  tbl_summary(by= b,
              missing = "always") %>%
  add_p() %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  as_tibble()
```

[image]

**This is what I get with "chisq.test"**

```
df %>%
    select(a, b) %>%
    tbl_summary(by= b,
                missing = "always") %>%
    add_p(list(everything() ~ "chisq.test")) %>%
    add_overall() %>%
    as_tibble()
```

[image]

Comment: Please either use a common dataset (e.g., `mtcars`, `iris`, `diamonds`, `starwars`) or share a sample of your data, then update your outputs to reflect the _sampled_ data.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for the `add_p()` function it states the default test is the chi-squared without the continuity correction, where `chisq.test()`'s default includes the correction.

https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_p.tbl_summary.html
[image]
I suspect that is the discrepancy you're seeing, but without a reproducible example it's impossible to say.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just edited the post adding a reprex

Comment: Ok, but does the above post answer your question?

Comment: Hello, I couldn't tell you if the difference is indeed due to that because I have no way of checking it.

Comment: You can check it outside of gtsummary using the argument to chisq.test() or from within gtsummary as well